# Is there a way to run initialization code in each uwsgi worker (after forking)

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, flask-script

Is there a way (in uWSGI or Flask) to register a function to be run in each worker *after* spawning but as soon as possible?

We have a flask app that benefits from preloading a bunch of stuff. The following only calls `preload` once for the 8 worker processes. The first request is fast, but the preloaded objects are shared in some fashion that causes errors.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
preload()
```

If I use [before_first_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request), then the objects are loaded in each worker process and there are no errors, but the first request is very slow.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_first_request
def bfr():
    preload()
```

I also tried setting up a flask script. Running the command works, but obviously the objects are loaded in the command's process rather than the uwsgi workers.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def preload():
    ...
```

I guess if we use `before_first_request`, we could manually trigger a request after restarting uwsgi. Is that the only solution here?

*edit: Just found the uswgi [hook-post-fork](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#hook-post-fork) option (and other hook options). I'm going to try that tomorrow. Maybe one of those is what I need.*

Comment: Are you using celery or some worker for dealing with background tasks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [postfork](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html#uwsgidecorators.postfork) decorator worked for me, just took a little while to find.

```
import uwsgidecorators

@uwsgidecorators.postfork
def preload():
    ...
```